# How to check Mouse Out of TabPage in C# Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to check the mouse leave of tab area of TabPage. but its not working properly. sometimes I get the messagebox sometimes not.

```
  TabPage mouseTab = null;

 void tabControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
      TabPage checkTab = null;

      for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabPages.Count; ++i) {
        if (tabControl1.GetTabRect(i).Contains(e.Location)) {
          checkTab = tabControl1.TabPages[i];
        }
      }

      if (checkTab == null && mouseTab != null) {
        mouseTab = null;
MessageBox.Show("MouseLeave");
      } else if (checkTab != null) {
        if (mouseTab == null || !checkTab.Equals(mouseTab)) {
          mouseTab = checkTab;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave(v=vs.110).aspx especially the `MouseLeave` parts.

Comment: why you are using MouseMove event instead of MouseLeave event??

Comment: because MouseLeave works for whole TabPage area, not for Tab area of TabPage.

Comment: You should use the Tab.MouseLeave event __in addition__ to checking the TabRect!